# Combinatorics problem: number of ways to arrange the letters $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $a$ is not followed immediately by $b$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange the letters $a, b, c,$
and $d$ such that $a$ is not followed immediately by $b?$

I am getting $6$ answer, but real answer is $18$

Comment: You might guess downvotes if you include [some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). For example, you could mention how you get the answer 6. Or what is the source of the problem (how do you know that the answer should be 18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subtract ways in which $a$ is followed by $b$ from total number of cases. $24-6=18$

Comment: ohh right ...tie man . Stupid question without thinking ask. Before ur answer it is not solve now solved .

Comment: Okay, you are welcome

Comment: Answer this also plz

Comment: In how many ways can a photographer at a wedding arrange six people in a row, including the bride and groom,
if the bride is positioned somewhere to the left of the
groom?

Comment: @sittian it's half the total number of arrangements.  In the other half, she's somewhere to the right of the groom.

Comment: got it ..tie sir .

Answer (score 2):

I know that other answers give you a brief idea how it is happening but I hope you will also take a look here.

Since there are objects $a,b,c,d$, so the total ways of arranging them is $4!$. Now, we want the number of ways in which $a$ is not followed by $b$. So just take the cases when $a$ is followed by b and subtract them from total number of cases.

i.e., Fix $ab$ and you will see total arrangement in which $a$ is followed by $b$ is $3!$, (remember you cannot arrange $a$ and $b$).

So, Total ways become $4!-3!=24-6=18$

Comment: hey wolf below is ur meal .. plz solve it

Comment: In how many ways can a photographer at a wedding arrange six people in a row, including the bride and groom, if the bride is positioned somewhere to the left of the groom? –

Answer (score 1):

The total number of permutations is $= 4!$

The total number of permutations in which $a$ is followed by $b$ is $=3!$

The total number of ways in which $a$ is not followed by $b$ is $$= 4!-3!$$ $$=24-6$$ $$=18$$